# React import/use Image (png) from Docker Volume

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, docker-volume

I need to use an image in a React project that is imported from a docker volume at run time.

Using images from within the react project is easy - just import the image and add it to the src e.g.

```
import logo from '../../images/logoWhite.png'
///
<img src={logo} alt="Logo"/>
```

But how would I go about doing this for an image on a Docker Volume? Do I need to 'expose' the image in some way or can I link directly to it?

EDIT: The app is running on docker and the image I'm trying to access is on the same container.

EDIT2: I've also tried the following but get a 'resource cannot be found' error

```
<img src={require('/resources/logoWhite.png')} alt="Logo"/>
```

Comment: Is your app running in docker, or are you trying to reach into another docker container?

Comment: Yes, the app is running on docker. I'm trying to access an image on the same container. I'll update the question to include this info.

Answer (score 0):

you can be used like this

```
<img src={require("../../images/logoWhite.png")} alt="Logo"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to get an image from a folder outside the project and I get an error saying the resource can't be found. 

For example: <img src={require('/resources/logoWhite.png')} alt="Logo"/>

Comment: Ok if any problem so let me know